# Wordpress: how to create posts programatically and check for duplications before

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a script that gets some data from an API and I need to insert this data ( array of posts ) into WordPress as posts.

So What I need to do are:

1. Check-in each post if it exists or not to avoid dubs by `post_name`
   or `slug` or `title` if possible
2. I have registered a custom taxonomy with the post called `newspaper`
   and I need to insert that newspaper whatever it's by `title`.
3. I have registered also custom fields with the post and the keys are
   `fifu_img_url`, `fifu_img_alt` and `_cmb_link` so I need a way to insert data to those keys for each post

This gonna be in a rest API post request, I have done the API part and receiving the data through the post request, what remain is handling the data as I described in above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this by the following

```php
$is_post_exists = post_exists($post->title);

if ($is_post_exists === 0) {
    $post_id = wp_insert_post(array(
        'post_title'    => $post->title,
        'post_date'     => $post->date,
        'post_content'  => $post->excerpt,
        'post_author'   => 1,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'meta_input'    => array(
            'fifu_image_url'   => $post->image,
            'fifu_image_alt'   => $post->title,
            '_cmb_link'        =>  $post->link,
        )
    ));

    $termObj = get_term_by('name', $post->newspaper->title, 'newspaper');

    set_post_format($post_id, $post->type);

    if ($termObj) {
        wp_set_object_terms($post_id, array($termObj->term_id), 'newspaper');
    } else {
        $new_newspaper = wp_insert_term($post->newspaper->title, 'newspaper');

        wp_set_object_terms($post_id, array($new_newspaper['term_id']), 'newspaper');
    }

    if ($post_id) {
        $added_posts[] = $post_id;
    }
} else {
    $not_added_posts[] = $post->id;
}
```

Comment: I am not able to get the featured image using fifu_image_url. Can you help with this?

Comment: fifu_image_url is a custom field I have registered not a featured image, to get the featured image any way you have to use `get_the_post_thumbnail()`

Comment: I need to set a fifu_image_url in the parameter in every post.I am posting the post using XMLRPC using PHP but the post is not coming with the featured image I already define the fifu_image_url in the custom field as well as the documentation defined by them but featured image is not appearing.

Comment: Check the Code: 
 `$content = array(
        'terms' => array('category' => array( $YourCategoryID ) ),
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_name' => $slug, //for slug
        'post_status' => 'draft',
        'post_title' => $title,
        'post_content' => $body,
        'ping_status' => 'closed',
        'comment_status' => 'closed',
        'meta_input'    => array(
            'fifu_image_url'   => $img_url,
            'fifu_image_alt'   => $title,
        )`